# Prepare Statement execute batch method inserting single record in database

Tags: java, jdbc

Prepare statement updating only first entry which we are setting through loop and rest are not getting inserted into database.

```
String INSERT_INTO_XYZ="Insert into xyz(col1,col2,col3) values(?, ?, ?)";

PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_INTO_XYZ);
int i = 10;
for(int employeeId : employeeIds)
{
    pstmt.setInt(1, i++);
    pstmt.setInt(2, group);
    pstmt.setInt(3, employeeId);
    pstmt.addBatch();
    pstmt.clearParameters();
}
pstmt.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
```

Comment: There seems to be something missing from the code, where is `pstmt.setXXX(1, XXX)` ? and what is `INSERT_INTO_GROUPMEMBERS` ?

Comment: Don't forget to commit the connection. [Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/). Try `conn.commit()` in the end.

Comment: still not working updating only values which are getting sated first loop iteration.

Comment: you're code appears correct are you sure that you loop more than once

Comment: Yes it is getting iterate 5 times

Answer (score 0):

executeBatch() should be outside your for loop.

addBatch() is used to add individual statements to the batch. The executeBatch() is used to start the execution of all the statements grouped together.

```
for(int employeeId : employeeIds) {
    pstmt.setInt(1, i++);
    pstmt.setInt(2, group);
    pstmt.setInt(3, employeeId);
    pstmt.addBatch();
    pstmt.clearParameters();
}
pstmt.executeBatch();
pstmt.close();
```

Comment: yes we are closing pstmt as you are suggesting but it is not working

Comment: @VinaySharma :: Try adding pstmt.clearParameters(); like in the answer inside the for loop for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. You should not require the clear parameters and since group  is not  changing in the  loop you can set that outside the loop.  The commit is only required if you have conn.setAutoCommit to false.  I assume that is the case  but you don.t show that in your code.